# Django Rest Framework url filter, import views error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm currently having trouble with writing Django Rest Framework filtering data by url. For some reason the problem seems to be when I import my views. The error points to the models which was working fine before I added the url filter in urls.py

```
File "/home/jd_dhang/drf-demo/project/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apps.core.views import SurgeryView
  File "/home/jd_dhang/drf-demo/project/apps/core/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import University, Student, SurgeryType
  File "/home/jd_dhang/drf-demo/project/apps/core/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class University(models.Model):
  File "/home/jd_dhang/drf-demo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 102, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class apps.core.models.University doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an applica
tion in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Django==1.9.13, djangorestframework==3.6.0

project/urls.py

```
**from apps.core.views import SurgeryView**

urlpatterns = [
    **url(r'^api/surgery/(?P<surgery_type>.+)/$', SurgeryView.as_view())**,
    ...
]
```

project/apps/core/views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import University, Student, SurgeryType
from .serializers import UniversitySerializer, StudentSerializer, SurgeryTypeSerializer

class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...
class UniversityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...

class SurgeryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet): #(APIView):
    queryset = SurgeryType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SurgeryTypeSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = SurgeryType.objects.all()
        surgery_type = self.kwargs['surgery_type']
        return SurgeryType.objects.filter(surgery_type=surgery_type)
```

Here are my models if it helps

project/apps/core/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "University"
        verbose_name_plural = "Universities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Student"
        verbose_name_plural = "Students"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class SurgeryType(models.Model):
    surgery_type = models.CharField("surgery_type", max_length=200)
    sub_type = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    available = models.BooleanField()
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='https://www.google.com')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Type: ' + self.surgery_type + ' SubType : ' + str(self.sub_type)
```

Thank you

project/conf/base.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger'
]
```

Comment: Is your app is included in the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Please add your `INSTALLED_APPS` from settings file in question

Comment: Hi, I've added my INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the import in your urls.py.

It should be `from core.views import SurgeryView` instead of `from apps.core.views import SurgeryView`